# UI Freezes on Invoking method channel

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to invoke method channel to apply a wallpaper.
I used [this](https://github.com/divyanshub024/chitr) repo as reference.

```
void _setWallpaper() async {
 showProgressDialog();
 var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(widget.post.url);
 try {
  final int result = await platform.invokeMethod('setWallpaper', file.path);
  print('Wallpaer Updated.... $result');
 } on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print("Failed to Set Wallpaer: '${e.message}'.");
 }
 Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

The dialog contains a CircularProgressIndicator and Text but the CircularProgressIndicator freezes and the whole UI is unresponsive for sometime. The wallpaper is applied and the UI becomes responsive.

Maybe it's because of the size of the images (around 5-10MB).

Comment: does this happen for both android and ios? I just checked android code, bitmap decoding may be thread-blocking, so I'd try running that code in a Service. Although it would take some time to correctly implement.

Comment: @AlexeySubbotin I haven't tried it on iOS.

Comment: then you definitely should rewrite that kotlin code as an android Service or atleast (don't know if the second works) as a separate thread. Especially if you try reducing the size of images and that reduces the freeze time, then the bitmap decoding is in fact breaking the thread computation, and computing the bitmap separately will help for sure.